# Gitlab CI - set variable using export

Tags: linux, gitlab, cut

I have the following URL:

NEW_URL = google.com/parentproject/subproject/ccc.git

```
echo $NEW_URL | rev | cut -d"/" -f1  | rev | cut -c -3
ccc
```

above command works perfectly fine but when I say

export DIR="$(NEW_URL | rev | cut -d"/" -f1  | rev | cut -c -3)"

I get **No such file or directory error**.. I tried to use escape characters around pipe delimiter but I did not get the result and only error..
I am trying to fetch ccc out of that url and export it to another variable ... Can somebody please help me?

NOTE: I am using this in Gitlab CI and trying to fetch the directory name between last / and .git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `echo $NEW_URL` instead of just `$NEW_URL`. As written, your code is:

```bash
google.com/parentproject/subproject/ccc.git | rev | cut ...
```

instead of

```bash
echo google.com/parentproject/subproject/ccc.git | rev | cut ...
```

so bash is trying to run `google.com/parentproject/subproject/ccc.git` as a command, which does not exist as per your error message.

As a side note, you can do what you are trying to accomplish with `basename`:

```
$ filename=$(basename ${NEW_URL})
$ echo ${filename}
ccc.git
$ cutname="${filename%.*}"
$ echo ${cutname}
ccc
```